# jQuery pajinate plugin customization problem

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, pagination

I am using Pajinate – A jQuery Pagination Plugin for pagination in my page

Following are my codes

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#paging_container6').pajinate({
                start_page : 2,
                items_per_page : 5  
            });
        });
```

HTML Code:

```
        <div id="paging_container6" class="container">
            <h2>Custom Start Page</h2>
            <div class="page_navigation"></div>

            <ul class="content">
                 <li><p>One</p></li> 
                 <li><p>Two</p></li> 
                 <li><p>Three</p></li> 
                 <li><p>Four</p></li> 
                 <li><p>Five</p></li> 
                 <li><p>Six</p></li> 
                 <li><p>Seven</p></li> 
                 <li><p>Eight</p></li> 
                 <li><p>Nine</p></li> 
                 <li><p>Ten</p></li> 
                 <li><p>Eleven</p></li> 
                 <li><p>Twelve</p></li> 
                 <li><p>Thirteen</p></li> 
                 <li><p>Fourteen</p></li> 
                 <li><p>Fifteen</p></li> 
                 <li><p>Sixteen</p></li> 
            </ul>   

        </div>
```

Pagination would be like this:

[image]

**Question:** When i reach first page I need to hide out `prev` button. similarly when i reach last page i need to hide out `last` button.

Is there is any option with this plugin or I need a solution for this pagination problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated on [this documentation page](http://th3silverlining.com/2010/04/15/pajination-a-jquery-pagination-plugin/) I don't really see if there is an inbuilt parameter or feature to solve your problem.

Comment: I know there is no option. but my recuirement is just as mentioned in my question. how to do that.

Comment: I just answered your `Is there is any option with this plugin` part, and the rest of the tweaking should be done by you, if you face any kind of technical glitch, then you can ask back on SO, but we are not here to solve the problem from Top to Bottom. Sorry.

Answer (score 5):

There is a solution. Per the documentation:

> A style class called 'no_more' is added to the first/prev links if the
>   first link is active and similarly for the last/next links. This
>   allows you to give these links a "disabled" appearance if required.

So just use CSS to hide the class 'no_more'.